# semicolon inside and outside Promise object

Tags: promise, raku

When I run the following code:

```
my $timer = Promise.in(2);
my $after = $timer.then({ say "2 seconds are over!"; 'result' });
say $after.result;  # 2 seconds are over
                    # result
```

I get

```
2 seconds are over!
result
```

What is the role of `;` inside the `then` and why if I write

```
say "2 seconds are over!"; 'result';
```

do I get the following error?

```
WARNINGS:
Useless use of constant string "result" in sink context (line 1)
2 seconds are over!
```

and not :

```
2 seconds are over!
result
```

like the first example?

Comment: The `{…}` is a bare block, similar to a subroutine.

Comment: Thanks its now make sense to me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`'result'` is the last statement of the block `{ say "2 seconds are over!"; 'result' }`. In Perl languages, semicolons (not newlines) determine the ends of most statements.

In this code:

```
my $timer = Promise.in(2);
my $after = $timer.then({ say "2 seconds are over!"; 'result' }); # 'result' is what the block returns
say $after.result;  # 2 seconds are over (printed by the say statement)
                    # result ('result' of the block that is stored in $after)
```

The second line could be rewritten thus:

```
my $after = $timer.then( {
                          say "2 seconds are over!";
                          'result'
                         }
); # 'result' is what the block returns
```

That semicolon simply ends the statement `say "2 seconds are over!"`.

Outside of a block, this line

```
say "2 seconds are over!"; 'result';
```

is really two statements:

```
say "2 seconds are over!";  # normal statement
'result';                   # useless statement in this context (hence the warning)
```

Putting multiple statements in one line rarely changes how they behave:

```
my $timer = Promise.in(2); my $after = $timer.then({ say "2 seconds are over!"; 'result' }); say $after.result; # Still behaves the same as the original code. ... Do not edit. This is intentionally crammed into one line!
```